# How to manually encrypt Devise password to massive insert sql data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to build a sql query to insert my users to the database, and set the user password to 'password', is there a devise default way to generate the encrypted password? say I want to password to be 'password'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the `password_digest` protected instance method on your model. Say your model is User, and the password in plaintext is "plaintextpassword" you have to do:

```
User.send(:password_digest, "plaintextpassword")
```

More details here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L152

Answer (score 1):

I had to call :password_digest on the instance object

```
User.new.send(:password_digest, 'password')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, "password")
```

will help you avoid having to initialize a User object